# Parsec: multiple possible options on one line

Tags: haskell, parsec

All,

I'm trying to write a parser using parsec. The goal is to eventually be able to parse a toy language.

Right now I'm struggling to make parsec recognise two different possible options, for example assignment and function invocation.

How would one write a "parseCode" function to parse the following:

```
x = 3
y = 4
plus(x,y)
```

into:

```
(Assignment "x" "3")
(Assignment "y" "4")
(Invocation "plus" ["x","y"])
```

Thanks

EDIT:

** omitted for brevity **

EDIT 2:

I built a bit upon your suggestions and now have the following problem
Running `parse parseTester "bla" "{plus(3,4)\nmin(2,3)\nx=3\n"` gives the expected solution: `Right (Body [Invocation "plus",Invocation "min",Assignment "x" "3"])`.

But running the functionally (almost) equivalent `parse parseBody "bla" "{plus(3,4)\nmin(2,3)\nx=3\n}"` results in an error:

```
Left "bla" (line 4, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting white space or "="
```

I don't see the problem. Is the parser suddenly looking for an assignment where it should be looking for an invocation? Any suggestions?

Code:

```
data Body = Body [Statement]
    deriving (Show)

data Arguments = Arguments [String]
    deriving (Show)

data Statement = Assignment String String
               | Invocation String
    deriving (Show)


parseBody :: Parser Body
parseBody = do
    char '{'
    statements <- many1 parseStatement
    char '}'
    return $ Body statements

parseTester :: Parser Body
parseTester = do 
    char '{'
    x <- many1 parseStatement
    return $ Body x

parseStatement :: Parser Statement
parseStatement = do
        x <- try parseInvocation <|> parseAssignment <?> "statement"
        return x

parseInvocation :: Parser Statement
parseInvocation = do
    spaces
    name <- many1 (noneOf " (")
    spaces
    char '('
    spaces
    bla <- many1 (noneOf " )")
    spaces
    char ')'
    char '\n'
    return $ Invocation name

parseAssignment :: Parser Statement
parseAssignment = do
    spaces
    var <- many1 (noneOf " =")
    spaces
    char '=' <?> "equal in assignment"
    spaces
    value <- many1 (noneOf "\n")
    char '\n'
    spaces
    return $ Assignment var value
```

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: I've added the code I have at the moment. Basically, parseBody should parse statements but I really don't have a clue where to start...

Comment: I see your first big problem.  You're trying to redefine the built-in `Maybe` type.  Just use it as `type Arguments = Maybe String`, don't redefine it yourself.  You'll also have to change `parseArguments = return Nothing` to get it to compile again.

Comment: I would also like to point you to the `Text.ParserCombinator.Parsec.Combinator.between` function, which will replace your `parseBody` and `parseCurlyBlock`.  Additionally, there's the `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char.spaces` function which skips 0 or more spaces to replace `parsePossibleWhitespace`.

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials for this sort of thing?  There's a [rather good one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours) on writing a Scheme interpreter using Parsec, I think that would be the best source of information, since this sort of thing can get complex and nuanced quickly.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that tutorial, indeed a very good resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we need to parse some choices, you could use `choice` from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Combinator`

```
choice [parseInvocation, parseAssignmen]
```

or much simplier: `try parseInvocation <|> try parseAssignmen`

P.S.

You could use form `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Char`:

```
many (oneOf " ") == spaces

oneOf " " == space
```